# Why am I getting a "unknown type name Opponent" error? (Details under code)

Tags: c++, debugging

player.h file

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

#include <iostream>
#include "cpputils/graphics/image.h"

class Player {
 public:
  // Constructor
  Player() {}
  Player(int x, int y) {
    x_ = x;
    y_ = y;
  }

  // Getters and Setters for x_ and y_
  int GetX() const { return x_; }
  int GetY() const { return y_; }
  void SetX(int x) { x_ = x; }
  void SetY(int y) { y_ = y; }

  // Getters for kWidth and kHeight
  int GetWidth() const { return kWidth_; }
  int GetHeight() const { return kHeight_; }

  // Draw
  void Draw(graphics::Image& GameImage) {
    GameImage.DrawRectangle(22 + x_, 27 + y_, 8, 9, 220, 0, 0);
    GameImage.DrawRectangle(5 + x_, 27 + y_, 9, 9, 220, 0, 0);
    GameImage.DrawRectangle(39 + x_, 27 + y_, 8, 9, 220, 0, 0);
    GameImage.DrawRectangle(12 + x_, 27 + y_, 10, 9, 90, 90, 90);
    GameImage.DrawRectangle(30 + x_, 27 + y_, 9, 9, 90, 90, 90);
    GameImage.DrawRectangle(5 + x_, 23 + y_, 42, 4, 90, 90, 90);
    GameImage.DrawRectangle(5 + x_, 36 + y_, 42, 4, 90, 90, 90);
    GameImage.DrawRectangle(12 + x_, 19 + y_, 27, 4, 0, 150, 255);
    GameImage.DrawRectangle(14 + x_, 15 + y_, 23, 4, 0, 150, 255);
    GameImage.DrawRectangle(16 + x_, 11 + y_, 19, 4, 0, 150, 255);
  }

  bool IntersectsWith(const Opponent& opponent);
  bool IntersectsWith(const OpponentProjectile& opponentprojectile);

 private:
  int x_;
  int y_;
  int kWidth_;
  int kHeight_;
};

class PlayerProjectile {
 public:
  // Constructor
  PlayerProjectile() {}
  PlayerProjectile(int x, int y) {
      x_ = x;
      y_ = y;
  }

  // Getters and Setters for x_ and y_
  int GetX() const { return x_; }
  int GetY() const { return y_; }
  void SetX(int x) { x_ = x; }
  void SetY(int y) { y_ = y; }

  // Getters for kWidth and kHeight
  int GetWidth() const { return kWidth_; }
  int GetHeight() const { return kHeight_; }

  // Draw
  void Draw(graphics::Image& GameImage) {
    GameImage.DrawRectangle(21 + x_, 7 + y_, 12, 13, 0, 220, 0);
    GameImage.DrawRectangle(24 + x_, 20 + y_, 6, 5, 0, 220, 0);
    GameImage.DrawRectangle(25 + x_, 25 + y_, 4, 17, 0, 220, 0);
  }

  bool IntersectsWith(const Opponent& opponent);

 private:
  int x_;
  int y_;
  int kWidth_;
  int kHeight_;
};

#endif
```

opponent.h file

```
#include "cpputils/graphics/image.h"

class Opponent {
 public:
  // Constructor
  Opponent() {}
  Opponent(int x, int y) {
      x_ = x;
      y_ = y;
  }
  // Getters and Setters for x_ and y_
  int GetX() const { return x_; }
  int GetY() const { return y_; }
  void SetX(int x) { x_ = x; }
  void SetY(int y) { y_ = y; }

  // Getters for kWidth and kHeight
  int GetWidth() const { return kWidth_; }
  int GetHeight() const { return kHeight_; }

  // Draw
  void Draw(graphics::Image& GameScreen) {
    GameScreen.DrawRectangle(17 + x_, 34 + y_, 20, 7, 155, 155, 155);
    GameScreen.DrawRectangle(10 + x_, 14 + y_, 34, 20, 155, 155, 155);
    GameScreen.DrawRectangle(17 + x_, 7 + y_, 20, 7, 155, 155, 155);
    GameScreen.DrawRectangle(10 + x_, 23 + y_, 34, 3, 60, 60, 60);
    GameScreen.DrawRectangle(28 + x_, 29 + y_, 16, 3, 60, 60, 60);
    GameScreen.DrawRectangle(10 + x_, 16 + y_, 16, 3, 60, 60, 60);
    GameScreen.DrawCircle(33 + x_, 18 + y_, 4, 60, 60, 60);
  }

 private:
  int x_;
  int y_;
  int kWidth_ = 50;
  int kHeight_ = 50;
};

class OpponentProjectile {
 public:
  // Constructor
  OpponentProjectile() {}
  OpponentProjectile(int x, int y) {
      x_ = x;
      y_ = y;
  }

  // Getters and Setters for x_ and y_
  int GetX() const { return x_; }
  int GetY() const { return y_; }
  void SetX(int x) { x_ = x; }
  void SetY(int y) { y_ = y; }

  // Getters for kWidth and kHeight
  int GetWidth() const { return kWidth_; }
  int GetHeight() const { return kHeight_; }

  // Draw
  void Draw(graphics::Image& o_proj) {
    o_proj.DrawRectangle(21 + x_, 7 + y_, 12, 13, 220, 0, 0);
    o_proj.DrawRectangle(24 + x_, 20 + y_, 6, 5, 220, 0, 0);
    o_proj.DrawRectangle(25 + x_, 25 + y_, 4, 17, 220, 0, 0);
  }

 private:
  int x_;
  int y_;
  int kWidth_ = 50;
  int kHeight_ = 50;
};
```

Basically, I have the declarations for the IntersectsWith functions in the player.h file, then the implementation for these functions in a different cc file. Im getting an error in player.h thats calling "Opponent" and "OpponentProjectile" unidentified types even though I have those classes created in the opponent.h file. I tried including opponent.h in player.h but that created so many redefinition problems that I assumed that was not the solution. Any help?

Comment: Off the top, `Player.h` uses `Opponent` but doesn't include `Opponent.h`. What errors are you getting when you do so include? You should concentrate on resolving those.

Comment: Looks like you need to forward declare `Opponent` in player.h

Comment: Unlike Java, the C++ compiler doesn't go automatically looking for files named the same as types.  It only looks in the files you tell it to (with `#include`).

Answer (score 0):

`opponent.h` should be made accessible by `player.h` by including the former in the preamble of `player.h`.

Also, there should be a `player.cpp` file with methods definitions, and that file too shall have a `#include "opponent.h"` line in the preamble.

Moreover, you declare `bool IntersectsWith(const Opponent& opponent);` two times inside `player.h` which leads to redundancy.

Here below the updated `player.h`:

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

#include <iostream>
#include "cpputils/graphics/image.h"
#include "opponent.h"  // added #include

class Player {
 public:
  // Constructor
  Player() {}
  Player(int x, int y) {
    x_ = x;
    y_ = y;
  }

  // Getters and Setters for x_ and y_
  int GetX() const { return x_; }
  int GetY() const { return y_; }
  void SetX(int x) { x_ = x; }
  void SetY(int y) { y_ = y; }

  // Getters for kWidth and kHeight
  int GetWidth() const { return kWidth_; }
  int GetHeight() const { return kHeight_; }

  // Draw
  void Draw(graphics::Image& GameImage) {
    GameImage.DrawRectangle(22 + x_, 27 + y_, 8, 9, 220, 0, 0);
    GameImage.DrawRectangle(5 + x_, 27 + y_, 9, 9, 220, 0, 0);
    GameImage.DrawRectangle(39 + x_, 27 + y_, 8, 9, 220, 0, 0);
    GameImage.DrawRectangle(12 + x_, 27 + y_, 10, 9, 90, 90, 90);
    GameImage.DrawRectangle(30 + x_, 27 + y_, 9, 9, 90, 90, 90);
    GameImage.DrawRectangle(5 + x_, 23 + y_, 42, 4, 90, 90, 90);
    GameImage.DrawRectangle(5 + x_, 36 + y_, 42, 4, 90, 90, 90);
    GameImage.DrawRectangle(12 + x_, 19 + y_, 27, 4, 0, 150, 255);
    GameImage.DrawRectangle(14 + x_, 15 + y_, 23, 4, 0, 150, 255);
    GameImage.DrawRectangle(16 + x_, 11 + y_, 19, 4, 0, 150, 255);
  }

  bool IntersectsWith(const Opponent& opponent);
  bool IntersectsWith(const OpponentProjectile& opponentprojectile);

 private:
  int x_;
  int y_;
  int kWidth_;
  int kHeight_;
};

class PlayerProjectile {
 public:
  // Constructor
  PlayerProjectile() {}
  PlayerProjectile(int x, int y) {
      x_ = x;
      y_ = y;
  }

  // Getters and Setters for x_ and y_
  int GetX() const { return x_; }
  int GetY() const { return y_; }
  void SetX(int x) { x_ = x; }
  void SetY(int y) { y_ = y; }

  // Getters for kWidth and kHeight
  int GetWidth() const { return kWidth_; }
  int GetHeight() const { return kHeight_; }

  // Draw
  void Draw(graphics::Image& GameImage) {
    GameImage.DrawRectangle(21 + x_, 7 + y_, 12, 13, 0, 220, 0);
    GameImage.DrawRectangle(24 + x_, 20 + y_, 6, 5, 0, 220, 0);
    GameImage.DrawRectangle(25 + x_, 25 + y_, 4, 17, 0, 220, 0);
  }

  // bool IntersectsWith(const Opponent& opponent); ELIMINATE THIS

 private:
  int x_;
  int y_;
  int kWidth_;
  int kHeight_;
};

#endif
```